# Ruby String Encode Consecutive Letter Frequency

Tags: ruby

I want to encode a string in Ruby such that output should be in pairs so that I could decode it. I want to encode in such a way that each pair contains the next distinct letter in the string, and the number consecutive repeats.

e.g If I encode "aaabbcbbaaa" output should
[["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]

here is the code.

```
def encode( s )
    b = 0
    e = s.length - 1
    ret = [] 
    while ( s <= e )
        m = s.match( /(\w)\1*/ )
        l = m[0][0]
        n = m[0].length
        ret << [l, n]
    end
    ret
end
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code for this?  If so, what does your code look like?

Comment: def encode( s )
    b = 0
    e = s.length - 1
    ret = [] 
    while ( s <= e )
        m = s.match( /(\w)\1*/ )
        l = m[0][0]
        n = m[0].length
        ret << [l, n]
    end
    ret
end

Comment: @HarisAli put your attempted code in your post description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"aaabbcbbaaa".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{|s, c| [c, s.length]}
```

Comment: Aha, deconstructing parameter assignment, nice.

Answer (score 8):

```
"aaabbcbbaaa".chars.chunk{|i| i}.map{|m,n| [m,n.count(m)]}
#=> [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this procedurally.

```
def group_consecutive(input)
  groups = []
  input.each_char do |c|
    if groups.empty? || groups.last[0] != c
      groups << [c, 1]
    else
      groups.last[1] += 1
    end
  end
  groups
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'aaabbcbbaaa'.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map {|e| [e[1], e[0].size]}
```

Comment: We came up with close ideas, which indicates we are on the correct line.